# Transition of SVG circle position results in truncation while moving

Tags: svg, d3.js

I have a number of `<circle>` elements each inside their own `<g>`.  To move the circles around I'm applying a "translate" transform on each `<g>`.

What I notice is that as the circles are moving, some of them seem to get slightly truncated.  As soon as they come to rest they look just fine so it is just while they are in motion. The truncation effect looks something like what you'd see if you had a square viewport the same size as the circle and then moved the circle slightly out of centre.  It just flattens slightly on one side.

This is what one of my element groups looks like:

```
<g class="datapoint dot" transform="translate(360,56)">
    <circle class="rendering" style="fill: #3182bd; stroke: #225b84; stroke-opacity: 1; fill-opacity: 1; " r="7"></circle>
</g>
```

When I run the transition watching the debugger I can see the values in "translate" change but everything else stays the same.  So it doesn't seem to be something I'm doing wrong, but you can never be sure of that. :)

One final comment is that I do see this in multiple browsers (tried Chrome and Firefox so far).

Has anybody encountered this kind of thing before?

Comment: I've noticed this as well and was curious about it

Answer (score 0):

Probably a bit late for you but I've noticed similar things when using `transform: scale()`. The SVG shape is limited to the files original size. If the shape gets enlarged bigger than this then it will be cropped.

My fix was to make the bounds of the SVG bigger than the shape itself so that it has some room to expand into.